# How can I add the beacon id?

Tags: swift, beacon

I would like to show on the screen the distance (Unknown, far, near or right here) and the ID of the found beacon. This is my code

```
struct ContentView: View{
    
    @ObservedObject var detector = BeaconDetector()
    
    var body: some View {
        if detector.lastDistance == .immediate {
            return Text("RIGHT HERE")
          // id here
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.green)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        } else if detector.lastDistance == .near {
            return Text("NEAR")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.orange)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        } else if detector.lastDistance == .far {
             return Text("FAR")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.red)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        } else {
            return Text("UNKNOWN")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.gray)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
       
    }
}
```

```
    import Combine
    import CoreLocation
    import SwiftUI


    class BeaconDetector: NSObject, ObservableObject, 
    CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var beaconID = UUID().self
    @Published var lastDistance = CLProximity.unknown
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
    didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: 
    CLBeaconRegion.self){
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable(){
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
     }
    
    
    func startScanning() {
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "D3D6736B-4C7C-412D-865B-EE61ACF88C61")!
        let constraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid, major: 123, 
     minor: 456)
        let beconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: 
    constraint, identifier: "MyBeacon")
        
        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beconRegion)
        locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: constraint)
        
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: 
    [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {
        if let beacon = beacons.first {
            update(distance: beacon.proximity)
        } else {
            update(distance: .unknown)
        }
    }
    
    func update(distance: CLProximity) {
        lastDistance = distance
        didChange.send(())
     }
    }

    struct BigText: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(Font.system(size: 72, design: .rounded))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, 
    maxHeight: .infinity)
     }
    }
```

Comment: What does the code do right now? What change in behavior do you want?  What have you tried?  You should show the code of `BeaconDetector` so we know how it works.

Comment: I want to show Major and minor of the scanned beacon

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Text("Beacon with major: \(detector.lastMajor) minor: \(detector.lastMinor) is RIGHT HERE")
  .modifier(BigText())
  .background(Color.green)
  .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

If the `BeaconDetector` class has a field for lastMajor and lastMinor you can reference these inside your string to be shown on the screen by escaping the expression inside the string with `\\()`.

---

Since the clarified code shows that the major and minor are not fields on `BeaconDetector` you will need to add them like this:

```
 @Published var lastMajor: NSNumber? = nil
 @Published var lastMinor: NSNumber? = nil
```

And then you will need to update them when you update the proximity like this:

```
update(distance: beacon.proximity, major: beacon.major, minor: beacon.minor)
```

And add these to your update function like this:

```
func update(distance: CLProximity, major: NSNumber, minor: NSNumber) {
    lastDistance = distance
    lastMajor = major
    lastMinor = minor
    didChange.send(())
}
```

Comment: Please read "[Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/128421)"
and "[Why is writing an “Update” section in an SO question frowned upon?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368283/128421)"